# Program doesn't work correctly due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, exception, arguments, jlabel

The program below doesn't want to work and I don't exactly know why.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

    public class Lab2Part4 extends JFrame {
        public Lab2Part4() {

        setTitle("My Pics");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);

        Icon carIcon = new ImageIcon("db10.jpg");

        JLabel carLabel = new JLabel("new Aston");
        carLabel.setIcon(carIcon);
        carLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

        JTextArea carTa = new JTextArea();
        carTa.setText("this is the new JB car");

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();

        labelPanel.add(carLabel);
        textPanel.add(carTa);

        contentPane.add(labelPanel, textPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Lab2Part4 myFrame = new Lab2Part4();
    }
}
```

Now it compiles and the frame comes on the screen but there is no image or label and the error in command prompt is the one below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.java:426)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane$1.addLayoutComponent(JRootPane.java:532)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1127)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:973)
    at Lab2Part4.<init>(Lab2Part4.java:27)
    at Lab2Part4.main(Lab2Part4.java:30)
```

Comment: Well, look at your line 27. What are your arguments? Do they match the definitions in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contentPane.add(labelPanel, textPanel);
```

please change your code to

```
contentPane.add(labelPanel);
contentPane.add( textPanel);
```

Refer https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/api/java.awt.Container.html for more information

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't give me any error now, but the frame comes up empty. No image or text on it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can change your code from `labelPanel.add(carLabel);
        textPanel.add(carTa); contentPane.add(labelPanel);
contentPane.add( textPanel);`
  to   `labelPanel.add(carLabel);
        textPanel.add(carTa);
        labelPanel.add(textPanel);
        contentPane.add(labelPanel);`